# Searching through a string input by a user for any value of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an object that looks like this: `var object = {"keyword": "next", "other word": "wrong", "test": "wrong"}`. I want to take the input a user enters into a text field and search that input for any of the objects keys. If it is a match I also want it to check if the value of that key is "next". If so I want it to be able to run a function. If a key matches but the value is not "next" I want it to `console.log` the value.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```js
var object = {"keyword": "next", "other word": "wrong", "test": "wrong"}
var match;
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    var text = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var options = Object.keys(object);
    if (e.keyCode == 13){
      if(options.some(function(element){
        match = element;
        return text.toString().indexOf(element) != -1;
      })){
        if (object[match].toString() == "next"){
          console.log("next");
          document.getElementById("input").value = "";
        } else {                         
          console.log(object[match]);
          document.getElementById("input").value = "";
        }
    } else {
      document.getElementById("input").value = "";
      console.log("A valid keyword could not be found in your response: please try again!");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input id='input' autofocus>
<div id="gamearea"></div>
```

This code works fine until I change what the object data at which point typing in "other word" will not only output "wrong" but also "A valid keyword could not be found in your response: please try again!" If you need it I can post more code but I tried to avoid just copy/pasting my entire file. Any solutions or even just pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Given an input, you can check whether it is a property of your `object` using [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty). Using bracket notation, you can then fetch the value of the property provided as input, to check whether it is equal to `"next"`:

```js
var object = {"keyword": "next", "other word": "wrong", "test": "wrong"};
var userInput = "keyword";

if(object.hasOwnProperty(userInput)) { // check that user input is a property . in object
  var value = object[userInput]
  if(value === "next") { // check that the value of the users input is "next"
    // run some function
    console.log("Value next, so we can call a function");
  } else { // the value is not next, so we can log it
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is an idea of how to solve the problem using the `Object.entries` method.

```js
const sentence = "This sentence has a keyword";

const object = {"keyword": "next", "other word": "wrong", "test": "wrong"};

const someFunc = () => {
  console.log("function!");
}

Object.entries(object).forEach(([key, val]) => {
  if (sentence.includes(key)) {
    val === "next" ? someFunc() : console.log('here');
  }
})
```

Comment: Two things to consider: https://caniuse.com/#search=includes and https://caniuse.com/#search=Object.entries

Answer (score 0):

Below is a basic example which will give you the idea using Object.keys

```js
var object = {"keyword": "next", "other word": "wrong", "test": "wrong"};

var yourSearchWord = 'keyword';

// Get the key names
var objectKeys = Object.keys(object);

if(objectKeys.indexOf(yourSearchWord) != -1) {
    if(object[yourSearchWord] === 'next') {
        console.log('The value is next');
        // Call your next function
    }
}
```

Comment: Not the one who downvoted, but your code needs to essentially do a linear search through all the keys in the object when you use `indexOf`, instead, there are faster approaches to checking membership of a key in an object. Also, maybe a little more of an explanation of how your code works might help your answer. Not sure if these are the reasons why u got downvoted though, just speculation

Comment: Yeah I do agree with you on that point Nick and like your solution too.